# How do we test synchronization code?

Tags: java, multithreading

Recently I am working on a piece of code involving synchronization and struggling on how to test it. To get into the problem, we can consider we are writing a unit test for a `CountDownLatch`:

```
CountDownLatch l = new CountDownLatch(1);

new Thread() {
    @Override
    void run() {
        l.await();
        System.out.println("good!");
    }
}.start();

Thread.sleep(1000); // wait for thread to run
if (the thread is alive)
    l.countDown();
else
    System.out.println("bad!");
```

So the problem is, there is no guarantee that the `sleep` for 1 second would be enough in all cases in all machines. So my goal is to eliminate this type of sleeping code to expect a certain state when testing synchronization, but soon realize it starts to become halting problem.

My current solution would be to query the state of the thread:

```
Thread t = ...
t.start();

if (t.getState() == Thread.State.WAITING) {
    l.countDown();
    assert(t.getState() == Thread.State.RUNNABLE); // or running or terminated
}
```

my questions are:

1. would that work? i.e. would the state of the thread will be toggled **atomically** at the moment, in this case, a count down latch reach a wakeup condition?(the doc says nothing about the change timing of the state)
2. do you have better suggestions?

Comment: Don't test the thread state, test the behavior. I can't tell what your code is trying to do, so I can't tell you how to test it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unit test synchronized code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825657/how-to-unit-test-synchronized-code)

Comment: @ИгорьДобровольський no, i am more on testing synchronization mechanism.

Comment: @DavidMoles for instance, how can i make sure `await` of the latch is actually blocking and write a unit test for it?

Comment: @DavidMoles let me explain more. in the case of synchronization, we involve sleep and wake up. without inspecting a thread's state, how can i ensure that the involved threads are in the expected state?(sleeping/awaken).

Comment: @HuStmpHrr You are asking the wrong question. The point of synchronization isn't to have threads in a certain state. The point of synchronization is to ensure that application state is consistent or that application code is called in a certain order. You should be testing your application code, not testing the system concurrency libraries.

Comment: @DavidMoles if i disregard the state of the threads, how can i know if my tests are passed by luck or an actual successful thread control? for instance, how can i prove my code of 10 threads concurrently adding 1 to a variable would work as expected in all cases?

Comment: By thinking through the possible cases and writing tests for them. FWIW, I've usually tested this sort of thing by putting the `Runnables` / `Callables` in question on separate single-threaded `ExecutorServices`, then having my unit test wait for them to finish (using `shutdown()` and `awaitTermination()`), with a timeout in case they don't finish in a few hundred milliseconds. There are probably better ways with Java 8 `ListenableFutures`.

Comment: What is purpose of such unit test? you do not trust Java when there is synchronized block of code and second tread will wait until first thread complete it? or what?

Comment: @Vadim i am not testing java. please do not get confused by my example. i cannot paste the code here so i put an example that everyone knows. imagine i am implementing a fork join thread pool and i need to test the join thread won't continue unless all workers are done.

Comment: Also: seriously, get ahold of a copy of [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/) and read it. There are much better ways to do almost anything than subclassing `Thread`.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr [Here's a unit test for ForkJoinPool](https://github.com/dmlloyd/jsr166/blob/master/src/test/tck/ForkJoinPoolTest.java).

Comment: dudes, focusing on my problem please... i am not posting in codereview...

Comment: I'm afraid you need to post something much more like your actual problem if you want useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into your example I have a feeling that you're using countdown latch upside-down. Why can't you do something like that:

```
    @Test
    public void testThreads() throws Exception {
        CountDownLatch l = new CountDownLatch(1);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Parallel thread is doing something.");
                try {
                    // instead of this sleep you put your logic that you want to be executed.
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                l.countDown();
            }
        }).start();

        System.out.println("Main thread is waiting for parallel thread");
        l.await();

        System.out.println("Done.");
    }
```

Please, correct me if I misunderstand your problem.

But generally speaking, I agree with one of the comments below your post that you should probably not test multithreading with unit tests.